# Bootstrap Popover emits Hide Event for the whole form

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, event-handling, jquery, popover

I have noticed a strange beheavor of Twitter Bootstrap Popover.

I have a modal window with a popover inside. I have a separete function for the "hiden" event of the modal form and a separate function for "hide" event of the popover. When I click the popover it pops up which is fine. When I click it again, it disapears which is also fine but it also executes the function written for hidden event of the whole form!

Here is what I mean:

```
$('#modal').on('hidden', function(event) {
    console.log("modal");
}

$('#popover').on('hidde', function(event) {
    console.log("popover");
}
```

When I click popover to hide it I get both messages in the console. Is there any idea why?

**UPD:** So the only solution I have found for this is to see what was clicked, i.e.

```
$('#modal').on('hidden', function(event) {
    if (event.target.id == "popover") {
        // popover was clicked
    }
    if (event.target.id == "modal") {
        // modal was clicked
    }
}

$('#popover').on('hidde', function(event) {
    if (event.target.id == "popover") {
        // popover was clicked
    }
    if (event.target.id == "modal") {
        // modal was clicked
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is called bubbling.
If an element triggers an event, all the parent elements will also trigger the same event.